# Multiple RabbitMQ Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-rabbit

I am trying to host multiple spring boot applications on a tomcat server.
However, I catch the following exceptions as i try to start the server up.
The problem is related to having multiple rabbitmq queues with the same caching factory id. 
I tried creating a ConnectionFactory bean with a different id in the ...Application.class, but the application failed to build.
Any help is welcomed.

```
org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [CachingConnectionFactory] with key 'rabbitConnectionFactory'; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection:name=rabbitConnectionFactory,type=CachingConnectionFactory
at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:628) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeans(MBeanExporter.java:550) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.afterSingletonsInstantiated(MBeanExporter.java:432) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:781) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5573) [catalina.jar:7.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147) [catalina.jar:7.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899) [catalina.jar:7.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875) [catalina.jar:7.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652) [catalina.jar:7.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1259) [catalina.jar:7.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1998) [catalina.jar:7.0.68]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_77]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_77]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_77]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_77]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_77]
```

Answer (score 3):

In our case we weren't using JMX specifically, and weren't relying on any of Spring Boot's JMX based features. Simply disabling JMX prevented the name clashes when deploying multiple applications to the same container.

In `application.properties`:

```
spring.jmx.enabled=false
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep using JMX, you can just assign it a unique `default-domain` in your `application.properties` like this:

```
spring.application.name=my-app
spring.jmx.default-domain=my-app-jmx
```

Found this solution [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/118#issuecomment-266049665), worked well for me. A brief description of the properties can be found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html).

Answer (score 1):

You should use a different MBean domain for each application.

However, there should be no problem creating the factory with a different bean name; you should edit your question to describe the nature of the problem there.

Comment: Setting different domain in _application.properties_ works only if i set my path to this file using `@PropertySource` annotation. If i decalre `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean in my configuration class and set a location there then i am still gonna get this exception.